# iterate through an existing observable collection gathering 2 of the properties in said classes c#

Tags: windows-phone-7, iteration, observablecollection

currently im using an observable collection called locationItems to to store my objects from a locations class.

on the page im working on i currently pass one object via selected index from the last page.
DataContext = App.ViewModel.LocationItems[index];

I would however like an option to iterate through all of the items in that ObservableCollection LocationItems { get; private set; } so that i can gather values from its objects created and plot them on a map.

so how do iterate through these ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The foreach statement comes to mind, assuming you are using C#.  As in:

```
foreach (var location in LocationItems) 
{ 
   ... 
}
```

Comment: that didn't work, tried that first :P,                I've now done it through       mapz.ItemsSource = App.ViewModel.LocationItems and populated it on the xaml using       MapItemsControl with datatemplate